# swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I am programming a small social network app for a community in Swift.

I got the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)` when I try to change views with         `self.presentViewController(FeedViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`. This line of code only executes if the user is allowed access to the second page.

Here is the full code:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

if passwordTextField.text == "" || nameTextField.text == "" {

    Global.showAlert("Erreur", message:"Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide!", view:self)

} else {


    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(nameTextField.text, password:passwordTextField.text) {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user != nil {




        } else {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.

            //var err = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString

            Global.showAlert("Erreur", message:"Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide!", view:self)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: When the user is successfully login, the view don't appear and xcode display this error

Comment: kkkkkk he is asking which line :)

Comment: Uhh sorry, afther the if user != nil{

Comment: i removed the line in the post -_-

Answer (score 0):

Based off be comments above it sounds like your app is crashing after the login. If that's the case:

Try changing `user!=nil` to `error == nil`

**UPDATE**

Check class permissions

Comment: Don't work :( do you have another suggestion please? :)

Comment: What are the permissions set to on your User class in the Data Browser. If "find" isn't checked that would explain it.